# c# getting NULL string from textbox of a other window

Tags: c#

As i said i am getting a null string from a other WPF textbox. I tried this code:

```
var window1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (window1 != null)
    {
        email1 = window1.email.Text;


    }
```

And also this one here:

```
MainWindow login = new MainWindow();
string txtname = login.email.Text;
```

Please help me!! Thanks! :D

Comment: Use the debugger to check if you really get a reference to MainWindow and then confirm that your code enters the if condition

Comment: ok but i dont understand. I am German btw. So the part with the if condition i dont understand @Steve

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger? This tool allows you to inspect your code while running and check if the code goes as you think.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019#:~:text=First%20look%20at%20the%20Visual%20Studio%20Debugger%201,Restart%20your%20app%20quickly.%20...%20More%20items...

Comment: ah ok thanks i will try it now!!! :D

Comment: i tried it it does not work there is no error i just dont get a string @Steve

Comment: it's again null

Comment: `.Text` can never be `null`, it will default to `""`. Check out the source [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,1593).